# Pandas averaging by specific row

Tags: python, pandas

I have table taht looks like following

```
A | B | C
__________
na| 1 | 2
3 | 3 | 4
na| 5 | 6
na| 7 | 8
2 | 9 | 10
na| 11| 12
na| 13| 14
3 | 15| 16
```

I would like to average all by column A. All the nan values till the number, final outcome should look like

```
A | B | C
__________
3 | 2 | 3
2 | 7 | 8
3 |13 |14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[pd.NA,3,pd.NA,pd.NA,2,pd.NA,pd.NA,3], 'B':range(1,16,2), 'C':range(2,17,2)})
df.assign(idx = [i if i in df.index[df.A.notna()] else pd.NA for i in df.index]).bfill().groupby('idx').mean().astype(int).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   A   B   C
0  3   2   3
1  2   7   8
2  3  13  14
```

Comment: Hi, please see the update in post. Your solution is a little oversimplified.

Answer (score 2):

You could backward fill column A and then perform a `groupby` with `mean()`:

```
df.assign(A = lambda col:col['A'].bfill()).groupby('A',as_index=False).mean()
```

prints:

```
     A    B    C
0  2.0  7.0  8.0
1  3.0  2.0  3.0
```

**EDIT:**

If you have the same values in column A, you will need to find a way to signal that a 3 on second row is not the same as 3 on the last row, which we can do with `diff()` and `cumsum()`. Then it's again a matter of `bfill()` and `groupby` with `mean()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: np.nan, 1: 3, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: 2, 5:np.nan, 6: np.nan, 7: 3}, 'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 9, 5: 11, 6: 13, 7: 15}, 'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 8, 4: 10, 5: 12, 6: 14, 7: 16}})

df.assign(new_A = (df.A.bfill().diff() != 0).cumsum()
          ).groupby(['new_A']).mean().reset_index(drop=True)

     A     B     C
0  3.0   2.0   3.0
1  2.0   7.0   8.0
2  3.0  13.0  14.0
```

---

```
pd.__version__
Out[46]: '1.3.5'
```

Comment: Hi, please see the update in post. Your solution is a little oversimplified.

Comment: I have addressed the issue. Please have a look

Comment: Current solution does not return A column

Comment: Can you check again? It works perfectly on my machine. What do you mean it does not return column A? use ```new_A``` in the groupby.

Comment: it returns B and C columns only

Comment: I can't help you if you don't give more information unfortunately. It does work on my machine and it prints what I show above.

Comment: Whar inforamtion could I give you?

Comment: can you do ```df.to_dict()``` which will allow me to reproduce your dataframe, and post it in your answer?

Comment: {'A': {0: <NA>, 1: 3, 2: <NA>, 3: <NA>, 4: 2, 5: <NA>, 6: <NA>, 7: 3},
 'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 9, 5: 11, 6: 13, 7: 15},
 'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 8, 4: 10, 5: 12, 6: 14, 7: 16}}

Comment: After I run the solution I get 

{'B': {0: 2.0, 1: 7.0, 2: 13.0}, 'C': {0: 3.0, 1: 8.0, 2: 14.0}}

Comment: I just run with your dataframe, an and I get the correct results.. What pandas version are you using?

Comment: the version is 1.4.2